# Escolher pasta para salvar um arquivo

Tags: python

Estou com esse código que eu seleciono o lugar para salvar o arquivo

```
    filename_2 = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg, "Select output file")
    self.dlg.pasta_saida.setText(filename_2)
```

porem eu gostaria de escolher a pasta para salvar o arquivo dentro
como ficaria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você deseja escolher o local onde o arquivo será salvo você pode usar o método `asksaveasfile` do modulo `tkFileDielog`, bastar fazer a importação das bibliotecas necessarias do `TKinter`.

Aqui segue um exemplo para você:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

def salvaarquivo(texto):
    f = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w", )#A foi opcao definida para escrita.
    if f is None:
        return
    f.write(texto)
    f.close()

salvaarquivo(raw_input("Digite um texto para ser salvo:"))
```

Documentação do [tkFileDialog](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476232/save-file-dialog-in-tkinter).

Obs: Caso você não tiver o `TKinter` instalado em sua maquina, você pode baixa-lo e insta-lo [seguindo as instruções](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter) do site do `TKinter`.

Comment: Funcionou no Pycharm, mas no qgis ele retorna none...mas obrigado pela ajuda de qualquer modo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar o seguinte :

```
import TkInter, tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
dirNome = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/",title ='Selecione a pasta')
```

Comment: não consegui importar essa biblioteca, estou usando o python para criar um plugin no QGIS, pode ser esse o motivo?